# Airflow backfill only scheduling for START_DATE

Tags: airflow, pipeline, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I just started using airflow and I basically want to run my dag to load historical data. So I'm running this command

```
airflow backfill my_dag -s 2018-07-30 -e 2018-08-01
```

And airflow is running my dag only for 2018-07-30. My expectation was airflow to run for 2018-07-30, 2018-07-31 and 2018-08-01.
Here's part of my dag's code:

```
import airflow
import configparser
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime

def getConfFileFullPath(fileName):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), fileName)


config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
config.read([getConfFileFullPath('pipeline.properties')])

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2018,7,25),
    'end_date':airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
}

dag_id='my_dag'
dag = DAG(
    dag_id=dag_id, default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)
...
```

So am I doing anything wrong with my dag configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:** `schedule_interval=None`

---

In order to initiate multiple runs within your defined date range you need to set the schedule interval for the dag. For example try:

```
schedule_interval=@daily
```

Start date, end date and schedule interval defines how many runs will be initiated by the scheduler when backfill is executed.

[Airflow scheduling and presets](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html)